# How to change basePath for Springfox Swagger 2.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, springfox

I'm running a service, where Swagger UI is accessible at:

```
http://serviceURL/swagger-ui.html
```

However, it is behind a proxy, such as:

```
http://proxyURL/serviceName
```

Generated URLs by Swagger UI are looking like:

```
http://proxyURL/
```

instead of the actual URL with the serviceName as suffix.
As far as I get it, this means manipulating the basePath property. As per documentation:

> A swagger API documentation can no longer describe operations on
>   different base paths. In 1.2 and earlier, each resource could have had
>   a separate basePath. In 2.0, the basePath equivalents
>   (schemes+host+basePath) are defined for the whole specification.

@Api(basePath) is deprecated, and it doesn't say what to use and how to use it. How to make the paths generated by Swagger appear properly?

I'm using **Spring Boo**t, Springfox **Swagger** and annotations.

Comment: were you able to resolve this @Martin?

Comment: I just did Docket.pathMapping("serviceName"), but I think this is just a raw workaround for missing functionality in Springfox, still waiting for an answer

Comment: Iḿ looking for the same thing..

Comment: Did you manage to resolve that issue @MartinAsenov?

Answer (score 16):

```java
@Bean
public Docket newsApi(ServletContext servletContext) {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
        @Override
        public String getApplicationBasePath() {
            return "/serviceName" + super.getApplicationBasePath();
        }
    }).host("proxyURL");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

### You can edit your **SwaggerConfiguration** like that:

> Take care to replace the `package` (which need to be the one
>   containing your REST controllers), the `host`, and the `PATH` you need

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static final String PATH = "/serviceName";

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        final var package = "com.martin.rest";
        final var host = "localhost:8080";

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .host(host)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(package))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        final var apiDocs = "/v2/api-docs";
        final var configUi = "/swagger-resources/configuration/ui";
        final var configSecurity = "/swagger-resources/configuration/security";
        final var resources = "/swagger-resources";

        registry.addRedirectViewController(PATH + apiDocs, apiDocs).setKeepQueryParams(true);
        registry.addRedirectViewController(PATH + resources, resources);
        registry.addRedirectViewController(PATH + configUi, configUi);
        registry.addRedirectViewController(PATH + configSecurity, configSecurity);
        registry.addRedirectViewController(PATH, "/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler(PATH + "/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

### Another solution is by changing the spring-boot URL **context-path**:

Edit pour `application.properties` file:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/serviceName
```

Or if you have an `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  servlet:
    context-path: /serviceName
```

Warning: **It will change the base path of all your web services, not only Swagger**

Comment: Changing the context-path looks easier, but as mentioned it could broke your api, just need to be aware of that

Answer (score 4):

Using spring fox 2.9.2, using solution mentioned by other users is not works.

What is not working:

- Overriding getApplicationBasePath on Docket pathProvider
- Adding server.servlet.context-path=/serviceName

I don't know why they are not work, but in my project that using Springboot 2.1.6.RELEASE and Spring 5.1.8.RELEASE, the two solution above is being ignored.

So, I am trying another approach: https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2817#issuecomment-517753110

According to the github issue comment, I need to override Springfox json serialize class and thank god this works.
Here is the code example:

```
import io.swagger.models.Swagger;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.JacksonModuleRegistrar;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.Json;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.json.JsonSerializer;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static io.github.jhipster.config.JHipsterConstants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION;

@Component
@Primary
public class CustomBasePathSerialize extends JsonSerializer {

    // this injection is optional, if you don't need to
    // add basePath based on active profile, remove this.
    private final Environment env;

    public CustomBasePathSerialize(List<JacksonModuleRegistrar> modules,
                                   Environment env) {
        super(modules);
        this.env = env;
    }

    @Override
    public Json toJson(Object toSerialize) {
        if (toSerialize instanceof Swagger) {
            Swagger swagger = (Swagger) toSerialize;
            String basePath = "/serviceName";
            List<String> profiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());

            // OPTIONAL: you can change basePath if you have difference path 
            // on any Spring profile, for example prod:
            if (profiles.contains(SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
                basePath = "/";
            }
            swagger.basePath(basePath);
        }
        return super.toJson(toSerialize);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's working only with Swagger 2, but still working a the moment

Answer (score 1):

I added the following config into my application.yaml file:

```
springdoc:
 swagger-ui:
  configUrl: /pathProvider/v3/api-docs/swagger-config
  disable-swagger-default-url: true
  urls[0]:
   url: /pathProvider/v3/api-docs/mobile-bff
   name: pathName
```

where pathProvider should be replaced by the PathProvider config in the old swagger 2 yaml...

and also, had do add a server into the OpenAPI object with the same PathProvider name.

```
@Bean fun springShopOpenAPI(): OpenAPI? { return OpenAPI().addServersItem(Server().url("/pathProvider"))
```

Comment: springdoc is another framework than springfox