# Adding base path to swagger documentaion

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am trying to change the base path of swagger codumentation. Currently I have

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/resourceName/v1")
```

and swagger config

```
 return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).
                select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo());
```

This is giving swagger base path as `"basePath": "/"`

I want to add base path as `"basePath": "/api"` so I followed diff threads like this [How to change basePath for Springfox Swagger 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198827/how-to-change-basepath-for-springfox-swagger-2-0and) and added

```
return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).
                select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.company"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo())
                .pathProvider(new RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                    @Override
                    public String getApplicationBasePath() {
                        return "/api";
                 }
            });
```

now the base path is changed to `"basePath": "/api"` and  I updated my path mapping to `@RequestMapping(path = "/resourceName/v1")` as base has been added.

When I send the request from swagger, the request is going to `/api/resourceName/v1` but the service returns `404`.

When I send the request through postman for `/resourceName.v1` then it works.

So the api is registred as `/resourceName/v1` and the base is just added by swagger on top of it and will not work if the request sent throguh swagger UI

Then I added `server.servlet-path=/api` to `application.properties` to register basepath in the request mapping and now swagger shows the base path as `/api` without needing additional configuration.

But the problem is now swagger documentation is available at `http://localhost:8080/api/swagger-ui.html` instead of `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html`. As we have all our other services doc at `http://host/swagger-ui.html` this is not useful.

Is there any way to add the base and still access the doc at `http://host/swagger-ui.html` and api's works as expected fro swagger and postman

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can add base path for all swagger requests. I used following config for this purpose:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SpringFoxConfig {
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();

        docket.pathMapping("api");

        return docket;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is way to change the api-doc base path using properties defined in application.properties file.

The properties are:

```
springfox.documentation.openApi.v3.path=/external/api/app/v3/api-docs
springfox.documentation.swaggerv2.path=/external/api/app/v2/api-docs
```

This can help you to change the path.