# Springfox swagger "try it out" hiting on localhost

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, springfox

I am using spring boot 2.2.4 to build a REST API, and springfow 2.9 for api doc.

I deployed the app in a docker container, and I am able to access the swagger-ui.htmlpage.
However, when using "ty it out" feature, the request is fired on the localhost url (https://locahost/api/find), instead of the service url (https://service.acces.url/api/find).
How can I fix that ?

swagger configuration:

```
    @Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("fr.test")) // only select API in this package
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            ;
}

// build some user friendly name and description for the API doc UI
private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("test")
            .description("test.")
            .license("Apache 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
            .build()
            ;
}
```

**EDIT**
I can see that the link to **/v2/api-docs** si well set, but couldn't find how they did in the source code...

[image]

Comment: possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198827/how-to-change-basepath-for-springfox-swagger-2-0

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you use the "**Try it out**" feature on Swagger UI, it would make an HTTP call on `localhost` itself. In case you want to override that behaviour, you need to set the `host` property of [Docket](http://springfox.github.io/springfox/javadoc/current/springfox/documentation/spring/web/plugins/Docket.html#host-java.lang.String-) with the required **hostname** as below:

```
@Bean
public Docket api(){
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .host("hostname")
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("fr.test")) // only select API in this package
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            ;
}

// build some user friendly name and description for the API doc UI
private ApiInfo apiInfo(){
    return new ApiInfoBuilder()
            .title("test")
            .description("test.")
            .license("Apache 2.0")
            .licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
            .build()
            ;
}
```

It would be ideal to get that `hostname` value from a configuration so that you can modify it when required without changing your code. And when you set it as `service.acces.url` as you require, the HTTP call on Swagger UI would be made to `https://service.acces.url/api/find`.

Comment: @UlkyIgor did this help?

Comment: sorry, got lost in my work.

Thank you for the answer. I already knew I could change the "host" in the API, but it will be difficult since the app service url is something that can change depending on the deployment environment (QA, PROD, ETC..). Furthermore, the app is deployed in a docker container and registered to an API gateway. Way too many params to take into account if I want to set the hostname manualy.

I see on the swagger ui that the link to* /v2/api-docs* (just bellow baseUrl) is well set, but I couldn't find in their source code how they did that...

Comment: UP.. still strugling on this :/

Comment: Setting the `.host()` can be used to kludge the proper path, but `.pathMapping()` works a little better. What we really need is an easy way to set Swagger's basePath parameter. --perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36198827/how-to-change-basepath-for-springfox-swagger-2-0